# How can I check if a SQL Server Index has been created ONLINE or OFFLINE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

We have a number of Indexes in our database and a number of environments we're deployed in, as each use a different version of SQL Server.

I'd like to be able to run a report to check if the Indexes were created **ONLINE** or **OFFLINE**.

I've tried various T-SQL queries on `sys.indexes` and beyond but can't find anything.

Google hasn't helped, here's hoping on the wisdom of Stack Exchange

Comment: There is no difference between an online and an offline created index when it is done. Both of them are just an index. I am not even sure if you can retrieve the information you need (why is it important, what do you want to solve?). If it is possible to retrieve this info, your best bet is the transaction log.

Comment: Hey Pred. I have to admit I'm mighty confused.
It's very important as I need to verify the built environments are as we want. And we want ONLINE indexes when they're available.

Comment: As Pred says, online and offline only matter whilst the `CREATE INDEX` or `ALTER INDEX` is running. It's completely invisible (and irrelevant) which option was selected after the index is built. And, of course, which option is used for any *subsequent* `ALTER INDEX` statement is a free choice to be made *at that time*.

Comment: Can't you just check your deployment scripts? The ONLINE=ON must be explicitly stated, it's not the default.

Comment: If you have to verify the change scripts, the do that. If you want to verify if all instances have the same structure, including indexes, then do a schema comparison using for example visual studio or a third party tool, maybe just write a script which can do that. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever stated it already, you can select ONLINE or OFFLINE methods at creation time, once the index is in place, the method was used to build the index is not important and makes no difference.

Comment: Ok so background:
- we're *trying* to use SSDT. It's proving stubborn
- I'm trying to verify POST build how they were built
I'm surprised I can't determine post-creation as clearly knowing whether they are ONLINE/OFFLINE could affect when we rebuild (as locks will be active during drop if OFFLINE). 
Hope that makes most sense. It seems I can't tell :-(

Comment: I don't know how else we can say it. Once they've been built, they're *neither* ONLINE *nor* OFFLINE. They're just indexes. *When* you rebuild them, it's up to you, *at that time* to decide whether to perform an ONLINE or OFFLINE rebuild. You can change your mind each time.

Comment: Cheers Damien_The_Unbeliever, dean, Pred.
You *ARE* getting through I'm just very surprised. It would be handy. I understand you all think it makes no difference, I'd respectfully disagree ;-)

Comment: First of all: some locks will be applied even when you are using the online option (the schema will be locked, some shared locks will be applied). You have to make sure, that your script is generated in a way to use online option (check your deploy settings). Keep in mind, that altering a table using a database manifest depends on the actions taken and lots of other variable (like the amount of data, the actions taken, etc). You CAN generate the alter scripts and edit them manually. Can't say in another way, after creation, there is no info about the method in use.